# How to resolve TRAMP spamming empty messages

Tags: debugging, tramp, vc

Connecting to a remote machine with tramp that may have VC (subversion) related
files, I tend to see a large number of repeated messages in the `*Messages*`
buffer.  For example:

```
Type "q" in help window to restore previous buffer.
 [2 times]
Mark saved where search started
 [69 times]
Mark saved where search started

...

Quit
mwheel-scroll: Beginning of buffer [7 times]
 [7 times]
Quit [2 times]

...

Quit
 [14 times]
Mark set [2 times]

Mark set

Mark set

Mark set [3 times]
```

Debugging this has been a pain and it's been very difficult to even get to
understanding that the issue is some interaction with TRAMP and VC.

Namely, I understood that in other emacs sessions, I didn't have repeated
messages.  Obviously the issue doesn't exist in `emacs -Q` either.
Furthermore, I tried the classic emacs configuration bisection, e.g., comment
out all configuration and slowly introduce sections until the error appears.
However, I was unable to uncover the issue with any of these methods.

Finally, I discovered some Emacs debugger functionallity for Emacs LISP.

I tried `M-x RET trace-function RET message RET`.  However, all I received was
quickly filling buffer of empty calls to `message`.

```
======================================================================
1 -> (message nil)
1 <- message: nil
======================================================================
1 -> (message "%s" "")
1 <- message: ""
======================================================================
1 -> (message nil)
1 <- message: nil
======================================================================
1 -> (message "Mark set")
1 <- message: "Mark set"
======================================================================
1 -> (message "Mark set")
1 <- message: "Mark set"
======================================================================
1 -> (message "%s" "")
1 <- message: ""
======================================================================
1 -> (message "%s" "Mark set")
1 <- message: "Mark set"
======================================================================
1 -> (message "%s" "")
1 <- message: ""
======================================================================
1 -> (message "%s" "Mark set")
1 <- message: "Mark set"
======================================================================
1 -> (message "%s" "")
1 <- message: ""
======================================================================
1 -> (message "%s" "Mark set")
1 <- message: "Mark set"
======================================================================
1 -> (message "Mark set")
1 <- message: "Mark set"
======================================================================
```

Which *is* the issue as described, but doesn't point to *where* the issue is
coming from.

I knew I needed the function call trace, as that will tell me what function is
calling `message`.

Next, I tried using `debug-on-entry` on `message`.  Finally, I have something!
(Actual file names changed for reasons).

```
Debugger entered--entering a function:
* message("%s" "")
  tramp-sh-handle-vc-registered(#("/ssh:remote-host:/some/svn/file" 1 4 (helm-ff-file t) 5 24 (helm-ff-file t)))
  apply(tramp-sh-handle-vc-registered #("/ssh:remote-host:/some/svn/file" 1 4 (helm-ff-file t) 5 24 (helm-ff-file t)))
  tramp-sh-file-name-handler(vc-registered #("/ssh:remote-host:/some/svn/file" 1 4 (helm-ff-file t) 5 24 (helm-ff-file t)))
  apply(tramp-sh-file-name-handler vc-registered #("/ssh:remote-host:/some/svn/file" 1 4 (helm-ff-file t) 5 24 (helm-ff-file t)))
  tramp-file-name-handler(vc-registered #("/ssh:remote-host:/some/svn/file" 1 4 (helm-ff-file t) 5 24 (helm-ff-file t)))
  vc-registered(#("/ssh:remote-host:/some/svn/file" 1 4 (helm-ff-file t) 5 24 (helm-ff-file t)))
  vc-backend(#("/ssh:remote-host:/some/svn/file" 1 4 (helm-ff-file t) 5 24 (helm-ff-file t)))
  vc-refresh-state()
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x215bf89>)()
  auto-revert-handler@bug21559(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x215bf89>))
  apply(auto-revert-handler@bug21559 #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x215bf89>) nil)
  auto-revert-handler()
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x215bffd>)()
  apply(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x215bffd>) nil)
  auto-revert-buffers()
  apply(auto-revert-buffers nil)
  timer-event-handler([t 24045 51629 615589 5 auto-revert-buffers nil nil 963000])
```

But, what is the solution to resolve this?

I have set `tramp-verbose` to `1`.  However, this might be hiding the
particular behaviour instead of spamming a load of messages about how
TRAMP is performing VC refreshing.

For now, since this is issue is being caused by some files under SVN control
that I have no interest in interacting with, i.e., it's not my repository and I
don't have write access anyways, I'm simply disabling the VC backend[[0](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Frequently-Asked-Questions.html)]:

```
(setq-default vc-handled-backends '(Git))
```

However, I would like to have a better solution in case I do ever need
to interact with SVN (hopefully not, but this feels very hacky).

This had led to the following [commit](https://git.devnulllabs.io/dotfiles.git/commit/?id=cf4d8b5d8e5892e7138476558c50431c21a08f5e) on my dotfiles, which also has some
other variables that may be in the middle of the interplay:

```
(setq-default auto-revert-check-vc-info nil)
(setq-default auto-revert-remote-files nil)
```

How might I more "properly" resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a solution yet, but I can explain a little bit. Your back-trace tells us, that the message call happens in `tramp-sh-handle-vc-registered`. And indeed, its body is wrapped by

```
(with-temp-message "" ...)
```

This is done in order to preserve the recent message in the echo area while running `tramp-sh-handle-vc-registered`, which has an own progress reporter.

Your back-trace tells us also, that this happens during `auto-revert-buffers`. Well, I agree with you that a progress reporter might not be helpful during auto-revert. This shall be suppressed in either Tramp or auto-revert.

An sx question is not appropriate to discuss possible solutions. I encourage you therefore to write a bug report, using `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

**Edit**: I've just committed http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=8aaa92a4b648aef137eb9a7054fdffaed04328ff to the Emacs git repo. This might solve the problem.

Comment: I have not yet had a chance to try your patch, however, since you have submitted a patch, do you still want a bug report?

Comment: No bug report needed. The patch will be included in Tramp 2.4.3, scheduled for end of the year. Will be available also via GNU ELPA.